# Why did Aaron Cross all of a sudden zone out?

Tags: character, the-bourne-legacy

In the movie [The Bourne Legacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bourne_Legacy_%28film%29), Aaron Cross goes to the Philippines in an effort to infect himself with a virus that will make him permanently more intelligent.

His reasoning is that he wasn't the smartest kid on the block before he was genetically enhanced. However on his way to get infected at the lab he starts to zone out like a space cadet as if his brain is failing.

Why does this happen?

Wouldn't he just go back to the way he was before versus becoming a vegetable?

Comment: I don't get the 'space cadet' reference.

Comment: Isn't that just a phrase used to describe someone who isn't all there? Not firing on all cylinders?

Comment: @TylerShads Nobby is correct, I thought it was a commonly used phrase, but thats probably because my wife calls me it all the time! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the catwalk, waiting for Marta to open a door, he just stared, once. That is all evidence the movie shows of him going back to his primal state. That hardly quantifies as becoming a "vegetable", as you say it.